# Get items permissions in OneDrive for Business using microsoft Graph API

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, onedrive-for-business, office-graph

I'm trying to get the **permissions** granted on items in personal OneDrive for Business drives using the **Graph RESTful API**.

Querying the OneDrive for Business:

> GET: graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives//items//permissions.

and :

> GET :graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives//root/permissions/

I'm getting the  following error :

> "code": "-2130575138, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException", "message": "MountPoint security error: host web isn't a personal site" However, if I send the following request :

How can I retrieve full permissions info using the Graph REST API?

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? I believe I am in a similar scenario...